# Как автоматизировать процесс выкладывания версий nodeJS приложения?

Tags: node.js, git, развертывание, gitlab

Смотрел я разные вопросы и гуглил, но все же обращаюсь к вам, опишу ситуацию. Есть приложение (веб-сайт) написанное на node, и с использованием модуля cluster для запуска на проде (может быть это как-то влияет на работу таких штук как pm или forever, пока незнаю). Все тестили на девелоперских машинах с виндами, cluster хорошо работает в паре с nginx. В общем все у нас вроде ОК, теперь пришло время выложить это творение на продовский сервер (там у нас хостятся сайтики на php с apache+nginx, пока node туда не ставили даже).

Проект хранится на сервере с gitlab, там и ведется разработка.

Варианты:

1. Нужно чтобы поле пуша в ветку master, срабатывал хук, который дернет "что-то" (можно написать sh скрипт который распакует ветку в нужную папку, но на сколько это правильно я не знаю), что обновит файлы в директории проекта, и тут же перезапустит рабочий сервер (например заставит forever перезапустить наше приложение).

   Очевидно что этот вариант плох, особенно если это приложение работает на нескольких разных машинах.
2. Никаких хуков, нужно "что-то" с веб-интерфейсом, и простым конфигом (типа указал адрес к репо, данные для авторизации, нужную ветку). Жмем какую-нить кнопку "Deploy" и файлы проекта обновляются, приложение перезапускается, профит.

Что посоветуете делать? А лучше тыкните на наглядные примеры, с подробностями.

Comment: *Очевидно что этот вариант плох* -- нет, не очевидно. Разверните мысль. И заодно разбейте на абзацы помельче :)

Comment: @D-side я полагаю плох тем, что такой вариант хорош только в случае если приложение работает только на одной физ. машине. как быть в случае если нужно обновить его на нескольких серверах?

Comment: А что связывает эти несколько серверов? Общий балансировщик нагрузки?

Comment: @D-side да, и локальная сеть.

Comment: @sanu0074 Вариант 1 - нормальный. На каждом из серверов делаем хук на отслеживание новых коммитов в master. При их обнаружении хук делает `cd папка_проекта && git pull ветка && npm start задача`. Схема рабочая, опробовано лично. Есть нюансы при amend/reset/revert, но это другой вопрос. При желании на каждом сервере делается свой sh-скрипт для запуска своей части проекта (пример: 1 поднимает сокет-сервер, 2 - http-сервер, 3 - сервер БД).

Comment: @MiKeBu спасибо, сделал уже с gitlab-ci

Answer (score 0):

ты описал ci/cd - так это называется. На самом деле вариант 1 (от которого ты быстро сам отказался) совсем не плох, если для деплоя/обновления не нужно пропихивать сложную асинхронную логику, которая цепляет различные приложения, то это отличный выход из ситуации: дёшево и сердито. По большей части весь ci\cd заключается в следующих пунктах:

1. подтянуть изменения
2. собрать проект
3. переместить директорию с билдом в нужное место

В github, gitlub есть куча инструментов, которые упростят жизнь. А по настройке самого ci/cd есть куча туториалов и видосов, дублировать их текстом в ответе не вижу смысла. Как раз при merge/pull/push в master и будет дёргаться твой сервер и будет запускаться sh скрипт.

P.s. веб-интерфейса, которые бы заменял бы "хуки" и сами авторизовывались на твоём сервере, насколько я знаю, нет. В том числе в целях безопасности, чтобы пароли от пользователя с доступом к созданию/удалению файлов и запуском приложений не утекали в "какие-то веб интерфесы" :)

Answer (score -1):

Для второго варианта можно использовать `keymetrics`.